# Ruby and RVM cannot install ruby-1.9.3-p392

Tags: ruby, installation, rvm

I check what versions of ruby I have with the right command.

```
Vincents-MacBook-Pro:~ vincentwarmerdam$ rvm list known
# MRI Rubies
[ruby-]1.8.6[-p420]
[ruby-]1.8.7[-p371]
[ruby-]1.9.1[-p431]
[ruby-]1.9.2[-p320]
[ruby-]1.9.3-p125
[ruby-]1.9.3-p194
[ruby-]1.9.3-p286
[ruby-]1.9.3-p327
[ruby-]1.9.3-p362
[ruby-]1.9.3-p374
[ruby-]1.9.3-p385
[ruby-]1.9.3-[p392]
[ruby-]1.9.3-head
[ruby-]2.0.0-rc1
[ruby-]2.0.0-rc2
[ruby-]2.0.0[-p0]
ruby-head
```

The list goes on and on but I can see that there are many versions of ruby 1.9.3. I try to switch to the newer version of 1.9.3, but I get an error.

```
Vincents-MacBook-Pro:~ vincentwarmerdam$ rvm use 1.9.3
ruby-1.9.3-p392 is not installed.
To install do: 'rvm install ruby-1.9.3-p392'
```

This seems odd to me because I can see `[ruby-]1.9.3-[p392]` appear in the list. When I try to install I suddenly get this:

```
    Vincents-MacBook-Pro:~ vincentwarmerdam$ rvm install ruby-1.9.3
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.7/x86_64/ruby-1.9.3-p392.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Installing requirements for osx, might require sudo password.
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
    suite-sparse.rb
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
Aborting
Error: Failed to update tap: homebrew/science
Already up-to-date.
Certificates in '/usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem' already are up to date.

apple-gcc42 is not available in PATH, try:

    brew unlink apple-gcc42 && brew link apple-gcc42

and make sure that apple-gcc42 is available in your PATH:

    which gcc-4.2
```

Could anybody explain to me what is happening? I've reinstalled RVM and I still get this message. I just want to be able to use ruby 1.9.3 so I can follow my first ruby tutorials.

Comment: Did you try to follow the instructions regarding the gcc? To install ruby, you need a compiler (gcc)

Comment: `list known` just lists all the versions RVM knows about. It does not mean you have all of them installed. You must install one from that list before you can use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

turned out that all I needed to do was install the command line tools for xcode. This removed all errors because now the gcc compiler works.

Comment: Can you add your resolution as an answer and accept it?  Also, these days you can install the command-line tools from XCode with `xcode-select --install` (assuming you have XCode installed)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like suite-sparse.rb is part of a git repository and it has been corrupted.  Try to find that file, cd to its directory, and run the `git checkout suite-sparse.rb` command on it.